# Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. ELB processes are not healthy

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an application via Beanstalk On Docker.

Application update in progress on 1 instance.0 out of 2 instances completed. My Beanstalk event fires an event that the container was added normally but soon

> "Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. ELB
>   processes are not healthy on 1 out of 2 instances. (running for 11
>   minutes). ELB health is failing or not available for 1 out of 2
>   instances. " Warning is issued.

The environment I have set up on Beanstalk is:

```
Application Load Balancer
- 443 / HTTPS / ACM / Active
- 80 / HTTP / - / Active

Proccess
- default / 80 / HTTP / - / "/" / Deactive
- health / 443 / HTTPS / 200 / "/health" / Deactive

Rule
- 443 / Default / - / /* / default
- 80 / Default / - / /* / default
```

Also, I am using Route53 and ACM, and I have registered the Beanstalk's LB in a new record.

What am I making a mistake?